# Select statement with multiple not equal where clause

Tags: php, mysql

In my **MySQL** i have **user_role_id** column

I want to select **all** from the table **tbl** where **user_role_id** is not equal to **1, 4 and 5**

Till now i use only for single not equal like

```
select * from tbl where user_role_id != 4
```

Kindly help me with the syntax for **multiple not equal**

Comment: `where user_role_id not in (1, 4, 5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the NOT IN Constraint for that which is available in the MYSQL.

**NOT IN() function:**

MySQL NOT IN() makes sure that the expression proceeded does not have any of the values present in the arguments

**Example:** If you want to fetch the rows from the table book_mast which contain such books, not written in English and the price of the books are not 100 or 200, the following statement can be used.

```
SELECT book_name,dt_of_pub,pub_lang,no_page,book_price  
FROM book_mast        
WHERE pub_lang!="English"     
AND book_price NOT IN (100,200);
```

Reference: https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/not.php

As per your code  you need to change the query like.

```
"SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE user_role_id NOT IN (1, 4, 5)"
```